# F# catching exception from lexer

Tags: exception, f#, lexer

I am trying to make my F# code catch an exception from the lexer for wrong input. Although the exception is raised, it is not caught by the other module. Can anyone help with this?

```
let lexstring expr =
    try
        LexBuffer<char>.FromString(expr)
    with 
     Lexer.IllegalCharacter  -> failwith "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

The lexer code is this:

```
| ['-']?digit+('.'digit+)?(['e''E']digit+)?     { FLOAT (Double.Parse(lexeme lexbuf)) }
// EOF
| eof   { EOF }
| _     { raise IllegalCharacter }
```

The error message is the following:

```
Lexer.IllegalCharacter occurred
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Exception of type 'Lexer+IllegalCharacter' was thrown.
  Source=FSharp.Core
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.Raise[T](Exception exn)
       at Lexer._fslex_tokenize(Int32 _fslex_state, LexBuffer`1 lexbuf) in E:\Programming\F#\fsapp_ozan\parser\Lexer.fsl:line 48
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Have you tried just catching all exceptions to see what you're getting?

Comment: Couldyou post the code from the "other module"?

Comment: This turned out to be an issue with the visual studio. It is solved now, though I am not sure how.